# PHP MYSQL valid query gives no error or result unless LIMIT added to query

Tags: php, mysql

This is the PHP i'm using it should yield a result of about 10300 rows with 2 values per row. Running this script is almost instantly completed and results in a white page no error feedback be it on screen or in the various apache and mysql logs.

```
$output = array();

$sql = "SELECT id, name FROM objects ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error());
$count = 0;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $output['records']['objects'][$count]['id'] = $row['id'];
    $output['records']['objects'][$count]['name'] = $row['name'];

    $count++;
}
echo json_encode($output);
```

However if change the query as such

```
$sql = "SELECT id, name FROM objects ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 500";
```

I receive my results as expected and the output (after json encode) seems to be about 31kb (31418 characters)

Am i simply exceeding some limit here and have my error levels set wrong?

Comment: Check Apache and PHP error logs!

Comment: How many records are in the `objects` table?  The obvious thing to check would be to see if too much data is being sent back; `LIMIT` might have alleviated this problem.

Comment: I have checked phps "php_error_log" apaches "error.log" and mysqls "mysql_error.log" and none of them have any corresponding entries.

Comment: How many records are in the table?

Comment: there are 10300 records in the objects table. But even setting the limit to 600 yields no result.

Comment: try `var_dump($output);`  and `var_dump(json_encode($output));` and see what you get. If you are getting the right data from the first `var_dump` and `false` from the second `var_dump` then I'd say that your data is causing `json_encode` to fail

Comment: You are correct the problem is in the `json_encode` not the mysql query, `var_dump($output);` yields the full expected results and like you predicted `var_dump(json_encode($output));` yielded a `bool(false)`.

Comment: fair chance the issue is one of the names contains a `'` which has been escaped by mysql and now looks like this `\'` which will be breaking the `json_encode` call - if that is the case you need to either strip or escape the slash

Comment: I added `echo json_last_error_msg();` to the script and it returned `Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded` I've managed to find the offending record but it doesn't look any different in phpmyadmin only when var_dumped does it display a `?` triangle character in the middle of its `name`.

Comment: Well it appears to have been 5 records that had a malformed space in them I've manually replaced all the spaces and it has fixed the problem thanks for your help @ever.wakeful

Comment: ha, no worries!

Comment: Incidentally, in my experience, counts are normally done inside a for loop, where the size of the for is equal to number of items in the array - but I don't know if it makes any difference.